# Textfield cannot be moved/is stuck on UIView

Tags: swift, uitextfield

I have been having an issue with a textfield within my app for about the last month and I haven't been able to figure out how to fix it. It hasn't been too much of an issue up until this point, but now that I am at the final stages of my app, it is causing real problems.

There are a few issues:

With auto-layout on:

No matter where I place the textfield within my view, when the app is run it jumps to x = 0, y = 0 underneath the navigation bar. I've tried moving it back to where it should be programatically, however this didn't work.

With auto-layout off:

Although with auto-layout off the textfield appears where it should be, I still can't move it anywhere as it seems to be stuck. This has become an issue now as I have just implemented code to move my UIView when a the user needs to type so that the textfield is not hidden.

This is how I am moving my UIView when the keyboard appears:

```
    func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
        //let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: keyboardSize.height, right: 0)
        var frame = self.budgetEntryView.frame
        frame.origin.y = frame.origin.y - keyboardSize.height + 167
        self.budgetEntryView.frame = frame
    }
}
```

Every UI element moves including other textfields however the problem textfield stays where it is.

Initially I thought the below code was the issue as if I remember correctly, removing it seemed to fix the issue. However I have just tried this again and the problem persists.

```
    func textFieldDidChange(textField: UITextField) {
    var text = textField.text.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(currencyFormatter.currencySymbol, withString: "").stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(currencyFormatter.groupingSeparator, withString: "").stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(currencyFormatter.decimalSeparator, withString: "")
    textField.text = currencyFormatter.stringFromNumber((text as NSString).doubleValue / 100.0)
    currencyDouble = (text as NSString).doubleValue / 100.0
    println(currencyDouble)

    valueEnter.alpha = 100
}
```

If anyone has any idea what the issue is then I would be very grateful because I have been completely stumped for the last month and I can't make any more progress until it is fixed.

Note: I created the textfield via storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out a solution. I had to recreate the textfield programatically. The textfield is now movable with or without auto layout on.